# Javascript - Problema con mensaje emergente en inició de sesión

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un página de inicio de sesión para cuatro tipos de usuarios (Admin, paciente, doctor, enfermerta) en javascript y tengo el problema de que al ingresar un usuario que no exista no se como hacer aparecer que no se encontró un usuario válido mediante un mensaje emergente en el navegador e intentado poner un else en el if que compara usuarios pero este mismo else se ejecuta por cada usuario que hay y resulta en cuatro mensajes emergentes uno tras otro y eso puede ser algo incómodo.

```
      if(usuario == response.nombre_Usuario){
```

Aquí la parte del código para mejor compresión, gracias de antemano por cualquier respuesta.

```
 function logueo(){
 
    var usuario = document.querySelector('#usuario').value
    var contraseña = document.querySelector('#contraseña').value

    var objeto = {
        'usuario': usuario,
        'contraseña': contraseña
    }

    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/AdminLogin/${usuario}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',}})
            //Parte del try-catch
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error:', err)
            alert("Ocurrio un error, ver la consola")
        })

        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.nombre_Usuario);
            console.log(usuario);
            if(usuario == response.nombre_Usuario){
                if(contraseña == response.contraseña){
                    console.log("registro exitoso");
                    alert("Exito!!! Inicio de sesión valido.")
                    sessionStorage.setItem("buscar", usuario);
                    location.href = "MenuAdmin.html";
                }else{
                    alert("Contraseña incorrecta");
                }
            }
        })
    
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/Paciente/${usuario}`,{
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',}})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error:', err)
            alert("Ocurrio un error, ver la consola")
        })
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.nombre_Usuario);
            console.log(usuario);
            if(usuario == response.nombre_Usuario){
                if(contraseña == response.contraseña){
                    console.log("registro exitoso");
                    alert("Exito!!! Inicio de sesión valido.")
                }else{
                    alert("Contraseña incorrecta");
                }
            }
        })
    
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/Doctor/${usuario}`,{
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',}})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error:', err)
            alert("Ocurrio un error, ver la consola")
        })
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.nombre_Usuario);
            console.log(usuario);
            if(usuario == response.nombre_Usuario){
                if(contraseña == response.contraseña){
                    console.log("registro exitoso");
                    alert("Exito!!! Inicio de sesión valido.")
                }else{
                    alert("Contraseña incorrecta");
                }
            }
        })
    
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/Enfermera/${usuario}`,{
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',}})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error:', err)
            alert("Ocurrio un error, ver la consola")
        })
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.nombre_Usuario);
            console.log(usuario);
            if(usuario == response.nombre_Usuario){
                if(contraseña == response.contraseña){
                    console.log("registro exitoso");
                    alert("Exito!!! Inicio de sesión valido.")
                }else{
                    alert("Contraseña incorrecta");
                }
            }
        })

}`
```

Comment: ¿Tienes una tabla para cada tipo de usuario? Eso no es correcto, deberías tener una sola para todos e incluir una columna para especificar el rol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo mucho código repetido, vamos a ver si podemos simplificar esa lógica:

- Para empezar, podemos ver que el objeto con las opciones de la request es el mismo para todas ellas. Pero es que además estás añadiendo un header que sólo tiene sentido en la respuesta del servidor: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` se usa para indicar que las peticiones desde otros dominios son aceptadas, no es algo que se ponga en la request.:

```javascript
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};
```

- Por otro lado, tienes que las respuestas son procesadas siempre de un modo muy similar, así que intentemos generalizar:

```
const usuario = document.querySelector('#usuario').value;
const contraseña = document.querySelector('#contraseña').value;

let datosUsuario = {
  'usuario': usuario,
  'contraseña': contraseña
}

function procesarRespuesta(response, perfil) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.nombre_Usuario);
    console.log(usuario);
    if (usuario == response.nombre_Usuario) {
      if (contraseña == response.contraseña) {
        console.log("registro exitoso");
        sessionStorage.setItem("buscar", usuario);
        datosUsuario.perfil = perfil;
        return datosUsuario;
      } else {
        alert("Contraseña incorrecta");
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Creé una función que procesa la respuesta y añade el perfil a objeto `datosUsuario`. De este modo podría hacer algo como:

```javascript
function procesarError(err) {
  console.error('Error:', err)
  alert("Ocurrio un error, ver la consola")
}


fetch(`http://localhost:3000/AdminLogin/${usuario}`, requestOptions)
  //Parte del try-catch
  .then(res => res.json())
  .catch(procesarError)
  .then(response => procesarRespuesta(response, "admin"))
```

- Pero vamos a realizar tres peticiones en paralelo, así que pensé que era un buen escenario para usar [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) (lo siento, no encontré documentación en español), que se completa cuando todas las promesas que se le pasen con parámetro se completen o fallen:

```javascript
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }

  function procesarRespuesta(response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.nombre_Usuario);
    console.log(usuario);
    if (usuario == response.nombre_Usuario) {
      if (contraseña == response.contraseña) {
        console.log("registro exitoso");
       
        return datosUsuario;
      } else {
        alert("Contraseña incorrecta");
      }
      return null;
    }
  }

  const perfiles = ['admin','paciente', 'doctor']
  Promise.allSettled([
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/AdminLogin/${usuario}`, requestOptions).then(res => res.json()),
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/Paciente/${usuario}`, requestOptions).then(res => res.json()),
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/Doctor/${usuario}`,requestOptions).then(res => res.json())
  ]).then(tresRespuestas => {
    tresRespuestas.forEach((respuesta, index) => {
      if (respuesta.status === 'fulfilled') {
        let datos = procesarRespuesta(respuesta)
        if (datos) { //si no es null
          datos.perfil = perfiles[index];
        }
        //... LOGADO CON LOS DATOS DE datos
      } else {
        console.log(`error en la ${index}ª llamada`); 
      }
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

Bienvenido MILONJAS,

He leído tu pregunta y se me ocurre una posible solución aunque puede que no sea muy elegante, espero que te ayude y sea lo que buscas.

Mi solución sería poner una variable booleana para controlar (por defecto su valor sería false y si el usuario es correcto se setea a true. Si al acabar de comprobar todos los usuarios dicha variable es false, se muestra el mensaje emergente).

```
function logueo(){
 
    var usuario = document.querySelector('#usuario').value
    var contraseña = document.querySelector('#contraseña').value

    var objeto = {
        'usuario': usuario,
        'contraseña': contraseña
    }

    var isCorrectLogin = false;

    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/AdminLogin/${usuario}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',}})
            //Parte del try-catch
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error:', err)
            alert("Ocurrio un error, ver la consola")
        })

        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.nombre_Usuario);
            console.log(usuario);
            if(usuario == response.nombre_Usuario){
                if(contraseña == response.contraseña){
                    console.log("registro exitoso");
                    alert("Exito!!! Inicio de sesión valido.")
                    sessionStorage.setItem("buscar", usuario);
                    location.href = "MenuAdmin.html";
                    isCorrectLogin = true;
                }else{
                    alert("Contraseña incorrecta");
                }
            }
        })
    
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/Paciente/${usuario}`,{
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',}})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error:', err)
            alert("Ocurrio un error, ver la consola")
        })
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.nombre_Usuario);
            console.log(usuario);
            if(usuario == response.nombre_Usuario){
                if(contraseña == response.contraseña){
                    console.log("registro exitoso");
                    alert("Exito!!! Inicio de sesión valido.");
                    isCorrectLogin = true;
                }else{
                    alert("Contraseña incorrecta");
                }
            }
        })
    
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/Doctor/${usuario}`,{
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',}})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error:', err)
            alert("Ocurrio un error, ver la consola")
        })
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.nombre_Usuario);
            console.log(usuario);
            if(usuario == response.nombre_Usuario){
                if(contraseña == response.contraseña){
                    console.log("registro exitoso");
                    alert("Exito!!! Inicio de sesión valido.");
                    isCorrectLogin = true;
                }else{
                    alert("Contraseña incorrecta");
                }
            }
        })
    
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/Enfermera/${usuario}`,{
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',}})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error:', err)
            alert("Ocurrio un error, ver la consola")
        })
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.nombre_Usuario);
            console.log(usuario);
            if(usuario == response.nombre_Usuario){
                if(contraseña == response.contraseña){
                    console.log("registro exitoso");
                    alert("Exito!!! Inicio de sesión valido.");
                    isCorrectLogin = true;
                }else{
                    alert("Contraseña incorrecta");
                }
            }
        })

        if(!Boolean(isCorrectLogin)) {
            alert("Usuario/Contraseña incorrectos");
        }

}
```

Comment: Te comento ya he probado con esa solución pero lo que pasa es que en el programa siempre se ejecuta de primero el if con booleano antes de los fetch, no estoy muy seguro pero creo que esto se debe a que son funciones asíncronas y están se ejecutan hasta de último, agradecería si alguien corrigiera o confirmara esto.

Comment: Si, ahora que me doy cuenta el código se sigue ejecutando sin esperar la respuesta de servidor de las funciones asíncronas. Se podría usar un await en cada fetch y hacer la función asíncrona. Dejo unos links con información, https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/ y http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/jsblog/es6-fetch-await.php